Not able to use Vpath when running Makefiles with Bazel?
I am running makefiles using Bazel and the CC_Foreign_Rules Library. While my Makefile can successfully build a lib when I use the make command, it fails to retrieve .c files when the makefile is run with Bazel. Is Bazel not compatible with vpath? Ex) vpath %.h $(HEADER_DIR). Is there any alternatives/changes to bazel to allow vpath?

Is your $(HEADER_DIR) a relative path?

It's the absolute path
